# Reopen same socket for reuse C++

Tags: sockets

I am having an application which listens on a particular RPC Port number say 10001 for connection with another device(hardware) using socket programming.

Meanwhile the hardware device will be trying to establish connection to my IP and same port number 10001.

So that way my application and the hardware are connected. Now assume i disconnect the network cable from my machine, my application would still be listening on port number 10001, however it wont receive any connection.

Now if i reconnect the network again then is it possible for me to reuse the same socket which i was using earlier for communicaiton with the hardware.

Do i sound confusing

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once an established socket connection has been disconnected, you cannot reuse that socket.  You must close that socket and allocate a new socket for a new connection.

However, pulling out the network cable on the listening end should not have any effect on the existing listening socket being able to accept new connections once the cable has been put back in.  If it is not able to do that, then your OS's socket stack is likely faulty.

Comment: Even i feel the same way. Probably some thing else is wrong with my code but i can see that my application is listening for a connection on that particular port number with and without the network cable

Comment: what are the  disadvantage of reusing sockets ?

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar Like I said in my answer, you CANT reuse a socket. The socket API doesn't allow for that (well, Windows has extended APIs to allow it, but that is a seperate issue). Once a connection has been broken, you have to create a new connection using a new socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for responding.I use okhttp3  for communication btw server and a client.I see every request  new socket with new port is being created.I see to many ports are opened from client side even when request is made to same address.My question why do not we use same ports instead of opening new ports.What are pros and cons re-using same ports? thank you .

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar You are not looking for *socket* reuse, you are looking for *port* reuse. That is a whole different matter. A new socket can be bound to a specific local port, it is just that most client software doesn't do that by default because it is generally undesirable to do so on the client side, you WANT a random local port chosen by the OS to be used for each new connection. Typically, the only time a client should ever bind to a specific local port is when a proxy/firewall or a network protocol requires it (and HTTP does not require it).

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar The OS has enough ephemeral ports available to it that this is usually not a problem on most client systems. It only becomes a problem if you are making a lot of new connections in a short amount of time. In the case of HTTP, if you are making a bunch of requests to the same address, you should be utilizing HTTP keep-alives and connection pooling, not using a new HTTP connection for each request, if you can avoid it. That will reduce the number of new connections, and thus the number of ports used

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your answer.If I would like to use keep-alive with HTTPS .What is the impact on SSL handshake ?

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar As long as the requests are sent to the same hostname, there is no impact if you use keep-alives. An SSL handshake is performed one time at the start of a new connection, and using keep-alives helps to reduce the need for making new connections.